# Twitter scraping for a project and am thwarted, but by what?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie. I keep getting an error that read: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. I keep reading it over and over...it's probably a comma or something. Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
setInterval(function(){ scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight) }, 2500)
```

Comment: This looks like javascript.  Did you mistakenly select the j tag instead of the javascript tag?

Comment: In JavaScript this error message is usually accompanied by a line number. You can even click on it and it will show you exactly where the error is.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Some examples or so.

Comment: That code doesn't generate any errors when I run it. You need to provide a [mcve].